# Cart Array is not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, state

I have a cart object with property items[] and want to update the ui when the user added a product button and the view cart is clicked a div is open with all the products in the cart.items[];

I initiated the items[] with a few products, and when I clicked on the view carts I see the products;
However, if  the items[] is empty and I click on add product to cart link and click on view cart I got nothing;

My problem is that the product is added but the ui is not updating. How can I fix it?

```js
Cart.viewCartItems = function() {
  var items = Cart.items; //JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("cart"));
  const cart = document.querySelector(".cart-view");

  if (items.length === 0) {
    cart.innerHTML = "<h2> Your car is empty</h2>";
  } else {

    cart.innerHTML = Cart.items;
  }
};
```

Comment: Do you invoke `Cart.viewCartItems` every time you view your UI ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. What did you try?